# MySQLfabric -- Manage setup problem

Tags: mysql, mysql-fabric

MySQL fabric does not get configured , getting these errors :

`[mysql@dev-dm-gitest101z /root]# mysqlfabric manage setup`

```
Error : 
[INFO] 1413953890.788408 - MainThread - Initializing persister: user (fabric), 
server (dev.local:3301), database (fabric).

Error: Command (CREATE TABLE providers (provider_id VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL, type INT
NOT NULL, username VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, password VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL, url 
VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL, tenant VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, default_image VARCHAR(256), 
default_flavor VARCHAR(256), CONSTRAINT pk_provider_id PRIMARY KEY (provider_id)), ())
failed accessing (dev.local:3301). 1071 (42000): Specified key was too long; 
max key length is 767 bytes.
```

`$ mysqlfabric manage setup`

```
[INFO] 1413955889.898494 - MainThread - Initializing persister: user (fabric), 
server (localhost:3301), database (fabric).

Error: Command (CREATE TABLE log (subject VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, reported TIMESTAMP 
/*!50604 (6) */ NOT NULL, reporter VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, message TEXT, category int NOT NULL, 
type int NOT NULL, INDEX key_subject_reported (subject, reported), INDEX key_reporter (reporter), 
INDEX key_reported (reported), INDEX key_category (category), INDEX key_type (type)), 
()) failed accessing (localhost:3301). 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'localhost:3301', 
system error: timed out.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have probably encountered a bug caused by your default server charset

[BUG #74192](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74192)